# How to re-encode a 120fps (or higher) MP4 from my Samsung Galaxy to a 30fps (example) so it plays on Windows like it does on the Samsung

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp4, slowmotion

I have some high fps slow-motion videos (mp4) that I've recorded on my phone, but when I copy them to windows and play them back, they play at the normal speed (or they play really fast), unless I slow down playback but this isn't a good result.

What I'd like to do is re-encode (if that's the right word) the video to a standard fps (such as 30) to get a longer video (keeping all the frames), i.e. a 10 second 120fps would end up being a 40 second video at 30fps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try using -r such as:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i inputSlowMotion.mp4 outputSlowMotion.mp4
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of these lines in the output console

[h264 @ 00000204287aad80] SEI type 6 size 40 truncated at 8 bitrate=7151.7kbits/s speed=1.06x

Is this to be expected, will it affect the output mp4?

Comment: @remark70 It's normal it's just ffmpeg working, it won't affect the output